# PolkadotJS ALICE address differs

Tags: polkadot-js, keyring

When I try to derive the Alice account with PolkadotJS I somehow end up with a different address than in the [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/subkey/#well-known-keys).

Here is the code:

```
const keyring = new (require('@polkadot/keyring').Keyring)();

let pair = keyring.createFromUri('//Alice');
console.log(`${pair.address}`);
// prints 5FA9nQDVg267DEd8m1ZypXLBnvN7SFxYwV7ndqSYGiN9TTpu
```

Prefixing the it with the dev menmonic `bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk` does not make a difference.

The unofficial [python bindings from polkascan](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface) and [subkey](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/utils/subkey) both yield the correct address:

```
from substrateinterface import Keypair

keypair = Keypair.create_from_uri('//Alice')
print(keypair.ss58_address)
# prints 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
```

Subkey:

```
docker run -it --rm --pull=always docker.io/parity/subkey:latest inspect "//Alice" | grep "SS58 Address"
# prints 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
```

Am I somehow using it wrong or why is PolkadotJS printing `5FA9nQDVg267DEd8m1ZypXLBnvN7SFxYwV7ndqSYGiN9TTpu`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you specify your keyring to use `sr25519` versus `ed25519` which I believe is default:

```
// Create a keyring instance
const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
```

See this [complete example](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/make-transfer):

```
// Import the API, Keyring and some utility functions
const { ApiPromise } = require('@polkadot/api');
const { Keyring } = require('@polkadot/keyring');

async function main () {
  // Instantiate the API
  const api = await ApiPromise.create();

  // Constuct the keyring after the API (crypto has an async init)
  const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });

  // Add Alice to our keyring with a hard-deived path (empty phrase, so uses dev)
  const alice = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice');

  console.log(`${alice.address}`);
  // prints 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY

}

main().catch(console.error).finally(() => process.exit());
```

Comment: Yea this works. Somehow weird that `sr25519` is not the default.

Comment: That is a good follow up question that I don't know the answer to :)